# Fructose question

Tags: diabetes, glucose, fructose, glycemic-index, triglycerides

See video: [Why Fructose causes insulin resistance](https://youtu.be/lV4eckv8bQQ)

I'm confused. He mentioned fructose can turn into glucose. So, does it matter whether I eat fruits, if it can turn into glucose, which can be metabolised by muscle after turning into glucose in the liver?

Also, the glycemic index showed that it is a mid glycemic index food for fruits. Can someone clarify? So we should opt for more flour based food instead than fruits?

I don't know about the fructose turning into fat in liver, which can cause insulin resistance.

Comment: That's a 9-minute video. I won't watch it and I doubt anyone else will either. Suggest you find something in text form you can quote, and I have no doubt there are plenty of sources out there.

Comment: Fructose generally turns to glucose more slowly than ingesting glucose directly. But the real answer here is - ask your medical provider for a nutritionist consult to guide your nutritional intake based on your condition(s).